# Creating a dynamic stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a system that fetches its data from different databases on the same server. These databases are newly attached to the server annually, e.g. at the at the beginning of 2013, a database called `2012` is attached.

I want to create a stored procedure that fetches the user's input which can be anything from 2005 (year). Based on the year the user enters, the stored procedure should go to that database (whose name will be the year the user entered) and search for the data (with its parameter being the year the user entered) inside the database which will also has a table with the same name as the database (i.e the table will have the same name as the year name).

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a good idea to parametrize the query.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROC usp_bar
    (@ID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(100)

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = @ID'
    SET @Params = N'@ID INT'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @ID = 5
END
```

Check out [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: thanx so much i borrowed a little sth from u and abszero and joined em to come up with a superdynamic sp :-))))))

Answer (score 0):

I am no DBA so take this with a grain of salt and understand there may be a better way to do this but what you will probably have to do is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_foo
@Year varchar(4)
AS

DECLARE @sql varchar(255)
@sql = 'SELECT * from [' + @Year + '].[owner].[table]'
sp_executesql @sql
```

Of course the user calling this sproc will have to A) have permissions to call system sprocs B) have permission to access the yearly database

Additionally, instead of going the SQL route, you could just make a dynamic connection string that you could populate with the correct catalog then issue your SQL queries directly to the database. Personally I would prefer that over using dynamic SQL.

Comment: thanx so much i borrowed a little sth from u and mrzulu and joined em to come up with a superdynamic sp :-))))))

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do, is take a look at synonyms, you could create one for each year:

http://sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Dyn_DB

```
CREATE SYNONYM otherdbtbl FOR otherdb.dbo.tbl
```

I'd recommend his site, it's full of good stuff, it's a great read :)

As to whether this works well for you, I'd expect it depends on how many tables you have in each DB. If it's a few this may work, if it's hundreds maybe another approach may work better - like abszero's suggestion of doing the switching in the application tier?